# Firefox Leaflet Not Displaying Map Shapes in Shiny App Default Page When Published on shinyapps.io (other browsers are working fine)

Tags: r, firefox, shiny, leaflet

I've just created my first Shiny app and published to the Internet - https://craycrayjodie.shinyapps.io/MapApp/

When launching the app and viewing in Chrome and I.E the default page ('Map' tab) loads as expected - with the "March" data displayed on the map. This is specified in the sliderTextInput for the page.

However, when I load the app and view in Firefox (i.e. the 'Map' tab), the "March" data is not displayed on the map when the app loads by default in Firefox. I need to move the sliderTextInput, then the data loads on the map in the Browser.

This is only an issue for Firefox, the other browsers (i.e. Chrome and IE) are fine and have the March data loaded and displayed on the map when the default 'Map' page loads.

I have published my files up to GitHub - https://github.com/craycrayjodie/DataVis

Also, my app.R logic is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(shinythemes)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(rmapshaper)
library(rsconnect)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(highcharter)
library(magrittr)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(shinycssloaders)
###################################################################################################

myAusdata_by_month_sf = readRDS("myAusdata_by_month.rds") #load previously saved datafile

myAusdata_by_month_5 = readRDS("myAusdata_by_month_5.rds") #load previously saved datafile

areas_by_weeks = readRDS("areas_by_weeks.rds") #load previously saved datafile

# Options for Spinner
options(spinner.color="pink", spinner.type = 7, spinner.color.background="#ffffff", spinner.size=1)

ui <- shinyUI(
 
  navbarPage(
    title = "Australians Mobility Changes During COVID",
    theme = shinytheme("yeti"),
    
    tabPanel("Map",
             div(class = "outer",
                 tags$head(
                   includeCSS("styles.css")
                 ),
                 
                 leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
                 
                 absolutePanel(bottom = 30, left = 250, draggable = TRUE,
                              
                # slider title, step increments
                
                sliderTextInput("choices", "Select month:", choices = unique(myAusdata_by_month_sf$month),
                animate = animationOptions(interval = 1500, loop = FALSE), grid = TRUE, selected = "March", width = 400))  
                
        
                 
             ),
             
               tags$div(id = "cite",
                      'Data downloaded from Facebook for Good by Jodie Anderson (2020).'
             )
    ),
    
    tabPanel("Story",
             
             highchartOutput("timeline", height = "800px" ) %>% withSpinner(),
             includeMarkdown("analysis.md"),
             
             br()
    ),
    
    tabPanel("Heatmap",
             
             highchartOutput("heatmap", height = "100%") %>% withSpinner(),

             br()
    ),
 
    tabPanel("About",
             includeMarkdown("about.md"),
             br()
    )
    

  )
  
  
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
    filteredData <- reactive({
        myAusdata_by_month_sf %>%
            filter(month %in% input$choices)
    })
    

    popup <-  reactive({
       
             sprintf("%s: %.1f%%", filteredData()$polygon_name, filteredData()$AvRelChange*100)

    })
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      

        mypalette <- colorNumeric(palette = "PuOr", domain = myAusdata_by_month_sf$AvRelChange, na.color = "transparent")
        
                leaflet(myAusdata_by_month_sf) %>%
                    setView(134, -29, 4) %>%
            addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") %>%
                     addLegend(pal=mypalette, values=~AvRelChange, opacity=1, title = "Mobility Change (%)", position = "bottomleft",
                              labFormat = labelFormat(prefix = "(", suffix = ")", between = ", ", 
                                                      transform = function(x) 100 * x))

    })
    
    observe({
        
      mypalette <- colorNumeric(palette = "PuOr", domain = myAusdata_by_month_sf$AvRelChange, na.color = "transparent")
        
         leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
            clearShapes() %>%
            addPolygons(fillColor = ~mypalette(AvRelChange),
                        stroke=TRUE,
                        fillOpacity = 1, 
                        color = "grey",
                        weight = 0.3,
                        label = popup(), labelOptions = labelOptions(
                          style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "2px 2px"),
                          textsize = "13px",
                          direction = "auto", offset = c(20, -25)))
      
   
         
         
    }) 
    
    output$timeline <- renderHighchart ({
      
      hc <- myAusdata_by_month_5 %>%
        hchart ('spline', hcaes(x= date, y=AvRelChange, group=NAME_1)) %>%
         hc_colors(brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")) %>%
        hc_title(text="Australians Mobility Changes", style=list(fontWeight="bold", fontSize="30px"),
                 align="left") %>%
        hc_subtitle(text="During the coronavirus pandemic", style=list(fontWeight="bold"), align="left") %>%
        hc_xAxis(title = list(text=NULL), plotBands = list(list(label = list(text = "Australia<br>in<br>lockdown"), color = "rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.1)",from = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date('2020-03-16', tz = 'UTC')),
            to = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date('2020-03-31', tz = 'UTC'))))) %>%
        hc_yAxis(title=list(text = "Mobility Change (%)"), showLastLabel = FALSE, labels = list(format = "{value}%")) %>%
        hc_caption(text = "The Change in Mobility metric looks at how much people are moving around and compares it to a baseline period that predates most social distancing measures.<br> 
The baseline period for this dataset is the four weeks of February 2020 (i.e. from the 2nd to the 29th).", useHTML = TRUE)%>%
        hc_credits(text = "www.highcharts.com", href = "www.highcharts.com", enabled = TRUE, style = list(fontSize="10px")) %>%
        hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, borderWidth = 2, valueSuffix = "%") %>%
        hc_navigator(enabled = TRUE) %>%
        hc_rangeSelector(enabled = TRUE) %>%
        hc_plotOptions(series = list(marker = list(enabled = FALSE), lineWidth = 4)) %>%
        hc_add_annotation(labels = list(list(point = list(xAxis = 0,yAxis = 0,x = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date('2020-07-13', tz = 'UTC')),y = 7),shape = "rect", text = "10th July: QLD opens borders", useHTML = TRUE))) %>%
        hc_add_annotation(labels = list(list(point = list(xAxis = 0,yAxis = 0,x = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date('2020-07-20', tz = 'UTC')),y = -22),shape = "rect", text = "30th June: Vic in lockdown", useHTML = TRUE))) %>%
        hc_add_annotation(labels = list(list(point = list(xAxis = 0,yAxis = 0,x = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date('2020-08-20', tz = 'UTC')),y = -30),shape = "rect", text = "2nd Aug: Vic restrictions ease", useHTML = TRUE))) %>%
        hc_add_annotation(labels = list(list(point = list(xAxis = 0,yAxis = 0,x = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date('2020-11-14', tz = 'UTC')),y = -41),shape = "rect", text = "16th Nov: SA restrictions in place<br>21st Nov: SA restrictions lifted", useHTML = TRUE)))
      
      
      hc
      
     })
    
    
    output$heatmap <- renderHighchart  ({
      
      hc1 <- areas_by_weeks %>%
        hchart(type = "heatmap", hcaes(x = date, y = polygon_name, value = AvRelChange)) %>%
        hc_title(text="Australians Mobility Changes", style=list(fontWeight="bold", fontSize="30px"), align="left") %>%
        hc_subtitle(text="During the coronavirus pandemic", style=list(fontWeight="bold"), align="left") %>%
        hc_boost(useGPUTranslations = TRUE) %>%
        hc_size(height = 5000, width = 550) %>%
        hc_colorAxis(labels = list(format = '{value}%'), stops = color_stops(10, rev(brewer.pal(10, "RdBu")))) %>%
        hc_legend(itemMarginTop = 75, layout = "vertical", verticalAlign = "top", align = "right", valueDecimals = 0) %>%
        hc_xAxis(labels = list(enabled = FALSE), tickInterval = 5, title = NULL, lineWidth = 0, tickLength = 20) %>%
        hc_yAxis(title=list(text = ""), reversed = TRUE, gridLineWidth = 0) %>%
        hc_tooltip(pointFormat = '{point.date} <br> {point.polygon_name}: <b>{point.value} %') %>%
         hc_credits(position = list(align = 'center', x = 135, y = -4), text = "www.highcharts.com", href = "http://www.highcharts.com", enabled = TRUE, style = list(fontSize="10px")) %>%
        hc_caption(align = 'center', text = "The white coloured boxes in the heatmap represent gaps in data.", useHTML = TRUE)
        
      hc1                                    
      
    })
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If a clever cookie can please advise on what changes I need to make to get the app working when the page loads with Firefox, that would be fabulous :)